# Hypercube inside isotropic convex body

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an isotropic convex body (i.e : barycenter at the origin, volume 1, covariance matrix a multiple of the identity).

The question of the greatest euclidean ball inscribed in K, meaning the greatest $c>0$ such that $cB_2^n \subset K$, where $B_2^n$ is often asked, but I would like to know if there is something known about the greatest hypercube inside $K$ ?

Can we hope for something like : There exists $c>0$ such that for every n, for every isotropic convex body $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a rotation $R \in \mathcal{O}(n)$ such that :

$$ cRB_{\infty}^n \subset K$$

Where $B_{\infty}^n$ is the hypercube of dimension n

In other words, setting $$c(K) = \sup\{c>0 \ \text{such that} \ \exists R\in \mathcal{O}(n), \  cRB_{\infty}^n \subset K \} $$

and

$$c_n = \inf\{c(K), \ K \ \text{isotropic convex body of } \mathbb{R}^n\} $$

I'm looking for lower bound on $c_n$ and hoping that $c_n \geq c$ for some absolute constant $c$. Of course one has the trivial upper-bound $c_n \leq 2$ for volume reasons

Comment: Why 'for every $n$'? Should the hypercube not have the same dimension as $K$?

Comment: Yes of course, but the question I ask is whether there is a fixed constant $r$>0 indepedent of the dimension such that we can stick a $r$-dilated hypercube inside any isotropic convex body